# O servidor responde com a flag RST/ACK depois do cliente enviar a flag SYN

Tags: tcpclient

Tenho estado a entender o porquê que o servidor X responde à solicitação de estabelecimento de TCP do cliente Y com a flag RST/ACK. Penso que o problema poderá ser um dos 3 abaixo.

1. A porta no lado do servidor encontra-se fechada;
2. Um pacote é enviado com algum problema e o servidor obriga-o a reenviar nova solicitação;
3. Tem alguma Firewall a barrar estas solicitações.

Após os pontos acima, a questão é:

1. Como posso saber que a porta no lado do Servidor está fechada? Realço que tem algumas vezes que a conexão é bem sucedida...
2. Como saber através do Wireshak que o pacote está mal formado?
3. O barramento da firewall é interna à rede do cliente ou na rede do servidor?

Answer (score 0):

O mais provável é que não exista nenhuma aplicação aguardando conexões naquela porta no servidor destino. O fato de que "às vezes" a conexão é bem sucedida indica que "às vezes" a aplicação no destino está no ar.

Poderia ser algum problema de firewall, mas aí é difícil de descobrir, é difícil saber o que tem no meio, a não ser que você controle o ambiente como um todo.

Poderia ser também pacote mal formado por problemas de hardware, alguma interface de rede, mas também não acredito nisso.

Meu palpite é que é um problema operacional mesmo: nem sempre a aplicação no destino está no ar.

Comment: Olá José X, obrigado pelo seu palpite. De facto é o que também desconfio...